# unknown_error when installing couchdb on android

Tags: installation

I was able to install CouchDB fine on my Samsung Captivate android phone using the app in the market. When I try and install it on my Samsung Galaxy I update the binaries, then I get an error:

```
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"badarg"}
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: What model do you have?  "Samsung Galaxy" covers at least a dozen phones.

Comment: Sorry you're right - it's a Samsung Galaxy Tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a strange error, currently there are 2 common problems with the CouchDB install,

1. is that it isnt currently supported on 2.3.3 and above
2. is that your external storage isnt mounted on /sdcard/ (or it is currently mounted as a drive)

are either of those true? if so then they are already on https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couch-android-launcher/issues and I will update there when they are fixed, if not if you could run `adb logcat` it would be extremely useful

Cheers
Dale

Comment: I would guess it's (2) -- my Galaxy S has external storage mounted as `/sdcard/external_sd/`.

Comment: Thanks guys - sounds like 2 is a good candidate, as I am running the stock firmware which I believe is 2.2 (I don't have it with me). I will check the mount point and look into changing it.